# Degree of canonical bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tangent-bundle

I'm reading theorem IV.5.3 in Hartshorne book and he says :  let $f: X \longrightarrow X^{\prime}$ be a canonical morphism of hypereliptic curve. Suppose $\mu=deg(f)\geq2$ and $d=deg(X^{\prime})$ than $d\mu = 2g-2$, because $degK_X=2g-2$. Why does this product equal degree of canonical class?

Comment: Since we are talking about the canonical map, the canonical class $K_X$ is the pullback of a hyperplane in $\mathbf P^{g-1}$. A general such hyperplane intersects $X'$ in $d$ points. Each of these points has $\mu$ preimages in $X$, so altogether we get $d\mu$ points on $X$.

Comment: By the way: 1) the result you mention is Proposition IV.5.3 in Hartshorne. If you are asking for help, you should give accurate references. 2) The text in your question is a _paraphrase_ of what is written in Hartshorne, not a quotation. That is perfectly fine, but when you paraphrase someone you should *not* use quotations marks.

Comment: @Lazzaro Campeotti Thanks, I'll edit

Comment: @Lazzaro Campeotti Isn't hyperplane section corresponds to very ample divisors?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the last question.